# How to upgrade from windows server 2008 r2 to windows server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I m using windows server 2008 R2 currently. I want to upgrade my server from 2008 R2 to windows server 2012? I don't have any disk to upgrade this? Is there anyway to upgrade without using the disk?

Comment: Please mention what's the role of your server cause suggested solutions might cause it to malfunction if not upgraded correctly .

Comment: its for using domain server so that related roles added in this and remote controlling roles added.. other than that nothing added...

Comment: I m using the roles are dns dhcp and remote controller otherwise no roles were added.

Comment: Then you have to download the iso file of server 2012 and select upgrade and not new installation